# Postgresql and optimal memory configuration

Tags: postgresql, memory

I have a Windows DB server with 112 GB (AMD TR 16 cores / 32 HT) of memory running PostgreSql v. 11.
I have looked into the documentation - but it is not clear to me exactly what  settings I need to change and which values would be the best fit for obtaining the greatest performance? Some advise would be really appreciated.

Comment: Probably better to ask this at https://dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/233582/postgresql-and-optimal-memory-configuration